# Launching a process in C# and passing an xml file

Tags: c#

I have the following code to run a cmd line based solver.

```
//Create process
        var pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        //strCommand is path and file name of command to run
        const string strCommand = // where .bat file is
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;

        //strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
        string strCommandParameters = " -xml '" + xmlFile +"'";
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommandParameters;

        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        //Set output of program to be written to process output stream
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //Start the process
        pProcess.Start();

        //Get program output
        this.StrOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        //Wait for process to finish
        pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

When I run it as is it exceptions out that it cannot find the file I am passing to it, when I comment out the UseShellExecute and RedirectStandardOutput it runs as expected but does not feed the information to my this.StrOutput, when I comment out the useShellExecute the redirect complains that the useShellExecute is not set to false.  How can I feed in my .xml correctly, and have the information from the cmd line feed into my strOutput successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **[StartInfo.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** to the right place before running the subprocess.  I suspect the current directory of the process is probably that of the output directory in visual studio.

Comment: I am feeding the complete path C:\.... for both the .bat file and the .xml file.  Am I missing something or should I be able to avoid setting the working directory if I did that?

Comment: have you tried testing the file path in this code before calling the subprocess? -- System.IO.File.Exists(file)